# How to efficiently fill a list with ray multi-processing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, reinforcement-learning, ray

I'm working on a project where I need to collect rollouts to fill a dataset and then train a model on it. I'd like to collect these rollouts in parallel to speed up the process so I'm trying to use the multi-processing provided by the ray library :

```
import time
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class MainActor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_set = []

    def process_item(self, item):
        # process incoming item
        item+=1
        return item

    def append(self, val):
        # add item to data set after processing it
        item = self.process_item(val)
        self.data_set.append(item)

    def train(self):
        # train on datatset
        return len(self.data_set)

main_actor = MainActor.remote()

@ray.remote
def rollout_collector(main_actor):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(40000):
        main_actor.append.remote(i)
    print("time per rollout : ",time.time() - t)


t = time.time()
ray.get([rollout_collector.remote(main_actor) for i in range(3)])
ray.get(main_actor.train.remote())
print("total time with multi-processing: ",time.time() - t)

# ============================== Single process ================================

class MainActor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_set = []

    def process_item(self, item):
        # process incoming item
        item+=1
        return item

    def append(self, val):
        # add item to data set after processing it
        item = self.process_item(val)
        self.data_set.append(item)

    def train(self):
        # train on datatset
        pass

main_actor = MainActor()
t = time.time()
for i in range(120000):
    main_actor.append(i)
main_actor.train()
print("total time with single process : ",time.time() - t)
```

The rollout_collector collect items and then store them, after processing, inside the MainActor to finally train on it. However, this method is extremely slow :

[image]

Each rollout when using ray take as much as 20 sec compare to 0.12 sec without ray and multi-processing. I have one cpu for the main actor and 3 for the rollout_collectors.
I don't think I can store the rollouts inside the rollout_collector workers and then send everything to the main actor as I'm using reservoir sampling for the training. Furthermore, I get a really long execution time for a very simple function when using ray : the training function on MainActor juste return the length of the dataset but it still take 20 sec to execute.

So my question is Am I doing something wrong ? What would be the best way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost of cross-process RPC (`actor.append.remote(i)`) is definitely going to be higher than modifying an in-process data structure (`list.append(i)`). The former involves serialization/deserialization, inter-process communication via system calls, and queueing since you are calling it from 3 concurrent worker processes. The reason `actor.train.remote()` took so long is probably also due to the 120K queued remote calls.

If realistically your rollout process takes more time, then multiprocessing should definitely speed things up. I added a `time.sleep(0.01)` delay to your `rollout_collector` and to the single-process loop at the end, reduced the number of rollouts to 400, then the multi-process version took 4.5 seconds to complete, vs. 13 seconds for the single-process version.

If your individual rollouts are very fast, consider batching the results locally in the worker process before sending them to the main actor.